# How can I prevent the screen jumping to Word when pasting ranges copied via VBA procedure in Excel?

Tags: excel, screenupdating

I have the following in an Excel VBA procedure:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

The code copies ranges from the Excel file and pastes them as tables into a new Word document. However, as soon as it pastes the first table the screen jumps to Word and everything going on (table formatting, etc) is visible to the user.

What do I need to do to keep the screen on Excel until all the copying and table manipulation is completed.

Thanks

Mick

This is the code that creates the new Word document, enters text and then copies/pastes the first Excel range. I tried Word.Visible = False but then the code fails on activating Word. If I don't activate Word, nothing happens.

Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()

```
Dim excelrange1 As Excel.Range, excelrange2 As Excel.Range, excelrange3 As Excel.Range, excelrange4 As Excel.Range, _
    excelrange5 As Excel.Range, excelrange6 As Excel.Range, excelrange7 As Excel.Range
Dim wordapp As Word.Application
Dim worddoc As Word.Document
Dim wordrange As Word.Range
Dim wordtable As Word.Table
Dim table5controw As Integer, table7controw As Integer, projectfinalyear As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

'Set up Word and copy/insert Excel ranges
Set wordapp = New Word.Application
Set worddoc = wordapp.Documents.Add
With worddoc
.Content.Font.Name = "Arial"
.Content.Font.Size = 11
End With
wordapp.Visible = True
wordapp.Activate

```
worddoc.Content.FormattedText.Text = "RRP Tables"
worddoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Bold = True
worddoc.Paragraphs.Add
worddoc.Paragraphs(2).Range.Bold = False
worddoc.Paragraphs.Add

Set excelrange1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary Tables").Range("Setup_RRP_Table_1")
    For m = 1 To excelrange1.Rows.Count
        If (excelrange1.Cells(m, 1).Value) = "n/a" Then excelrange1.Cells(m, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next m
excelrange1.Copy
worddoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Paste
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. With no code this is a shot in the darkness but sounds like you may benefit making the Word app no visible

Comment: more code please, it's impossible to detect a problem with such a few information

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the responses. I tried making the Word app not visible at the start and visible at the end but it didn't work. It's quite lengthy code but I'll show the section where it first transfers to Word. I'm not sure how to respond to individual responses or add to the thread - being new to SO.

Comment: Afraid that because I don't know how posting in SO works, the code in the edit to the original question looks a mess.